# "Undefined variable: _" error

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I'm getting this notice `"Undefined variable: _ in magic_quotes_gpc.php on line 43"` from this script:

```
<?php
$HTTP_VARs = array(
    'HTTP_GET_VARS' => '_GET',
    'HTTP_POST_VARS' => '_POST',
    'HTTP_COOKIE_VARS' => '_COOKIE',
    'HTTP_SERVER_VARS' => '!_SERVER',
    'HTTP_ENV_VARS' => '!_ENV',
    'HTTP_POST_FILES' => '!_FILES'
);

if (!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS) && isset($_GET)) {
    foreach ($HTTP_VARs as $HTTP_VAR => $_VAR) {
        $_VAR = ($_VAR[0] == '!' ? str_replace('!', '', $_VAR) : $_VAR);

        if (isset($$_VAR))
            $$HTTP_VAR = $$_VAR;
    }
}

function strip_magic_quotes($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        $array[$key] = (is_array($value) ? strip_magic_quotes($value) : stripslashes($value));

    return $array;
}

foreach ($HTTP_VARs as $HTTP_VAR => $_VAR) {
    if ($_VAR[0] != '!') {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            if (!empty($$_VAR))
                $$_VAR = strip_magic_quotes($$_VAR);
        } else {
            if (is_array($$_VAR)) {
                foreach ($$_VAR as $k => $v) {
                    if (is_array($$_VAR[$k])) {
                        foreach ($$_VAR[$k] as $k2 => $v2)
                            $$_VAR[$k][$k2] = addslashes($v2);

                        @reset($$_VAR[$k]);
                    } else
                        $$_VAR[$k] = addslashes($v);
                }

                @reset($$_VAR);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Line 43 is this: `if (is_array($$_VAR[$k]))`
I used echo to post all values and not a single 1 is `_`.

I looked and looked and have no idea where this variable `_` is coming from, I'm baffled.

Comment: Please don't use variable variables.

Comment: There's better tested code for that in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php (Albeit it's not quite clear why your script alternates between removal and `addslashes`)

Comment: Please don't use @ : http://derickrethans.nl/five-reasons-why-the-shutop-operator-should-be-avoided.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOA! I don't know what you're trying to achieve with that massive chunk of code, but you can deal with magic quotes using the following (much simpler) code:

```
/** Recursive array version of stripslashes. */
function stripslashes_deep($value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ? array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) : stripslashes($value);
    return $value;
}
/** Remove magic quotes if enabled. */
function nuke_magic_quotes() {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
        $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
        $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
        $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well my code adds slashes if get_magic_quotes_gpc() it's disabled

Comment: @alex2005: That's precisely why that code of yours is awful. Read up on proper SQL escaping (mysql_real_escape_string) or bound parameters.

Comment: Why ON EARTH would you want to do that? Magic quotes are totally, UTTERLY broken. They SHOULD NOT be used, EVER. That's why everyone strips them out, in case they're using a dumb webhost who has it switched on.